# eBay finding API GET returning few results

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to get the results from the api to match the website and the API is always returning fewer results than displayed on the website. I know of the 30 day limition of the API. Can someone help spot the error in my call?

I am looking for completed listings that have been sold

---

Returns 0 results:

> http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findCompletedItems&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=######&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=mike+trout+2009+auto&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=100&itemFilter(0).name=SoldItemsOnly&itemFilter(0).value=true&sortOrder=EndTimeSoonest

Returns 30 results for within 30 days:

> http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_nkw=mike%20trout%202009%20auto&_pppn=r1&scp=ce0

---

Returns 1 result:

> http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findCompletedItems&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=######&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=2011+bryce+harper+autograph&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=100&itemFilter(0).name=SoldItemsOnly&itemFilter(0).value=true&sortOrder=EndTimeSoonest

Returns 52 results:

> http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_nkw=2011%20bryce%20harper%20autograph&_pppn=r1&scp=ce0

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that lots of users are reporting the same issue, so it is a eBay fault. Thanks for looking!

https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/18851/is-anyone-else-having-problems-with-their-findcomp.html?page=3&pageSize=10&sort=votes